# Find customers that re-ordered the same purchase, MySql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 3 tables: users, orders and order_prices with the latter containing the analysis of each order and I need to find the customers that re-ordered in a specific month, ( both tables have user_id, order_id, order_date, good_id(only order_prices) etc) my script is the following:

```
select o.system_id, o.user_id, o.date, o.id 

from orders o

where o.date >= '2018-11-01' and o.date <= '2018-11-30' -- in the date range
AND o.user_id in 
            (   -- has made the same order (content)
                select op.user_id 

                from order_prices op join users u on u.id = op.user_id

                where op.good_id in 
                            (                                                      
                                select good_id 

                                from order_prices 

                                where user_id = o.user_id

                            )

                    And u.number_of_orders > 0 -- has ordered before

            ) 


group by o.user_id
```

Well i am not sure if this even works logically, also I guess I need to find those users that their previous order was the same in content with their last order the above script doesn't take into consideration.... any suggestions MORE than welcome!

Comment: Share some sample data~

Comment: @Vivek I ended up using a dedicated table from the database on re-ordering (the same last order) or re-ordering some previous order) s it was a night mare to do this just by going through the order records... but thanks anyway man!